# Responsive Nav bar overlapping on content in angular

Tags: html, css, angular, responsive

I have `nav` like below

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light navbar-fixed-top ">
    <!-- <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a> -->
    <button class="navbar-toggler" (click)="collapse=!collapse" type="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span #tasknote class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="navbar-collapse" (click)="collapse=true" [hidden]="collapse">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto sub-menu dl-submenu">
            <li class="nav-item menu-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item menu-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item menu-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">first</a>
            </li>

        </ul>

    </div>
</nav>
```

and remaining content section like below

```
<div>
//some content here
</div>
```

When I click on `Navabar-toggler` it overlapping on content in responsive. 
How we can rectify in angular 4 project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can Achieved by following way

**component.ts**

```
classIsSet=false
toggleClass()
  {
   this.classIsSet=!this.classIsSet;
  }
```

**component.html**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light navbar-fixed-top ">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" (click)="collapse=!collapse" type="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"
        (click)="toggleClass()">
        <span #tasknote class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="navbar-collapse" (click)="collapse=true" [hidden]="collapse">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto sub-menu dl-submenu">
            <li class="nav-item menu-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item menu-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
            </li>
             <li class="nav-item menu-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">first</a>
                </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

//content section

```
<div [ngClass]="{'res-nav':!classIsSet,'res-nav':classIsSet}">
//your required content
</dv>
```

**component.css**

```
.res-nav{
margin-top: 200px;//your required top size
}
```

Hope it will solve your proble !!